# cannot start android application on emulator

Tags: java, android

i am trying to run an application on adroid which consists of a quizz. however everytime i try to launch it on the virtal device, it keeps stopping, making it impossible to run. here is the java code:

```
 mFamilyName = findViewById(R.id.text2);// permet de lier la balise concernée dans le XML
 mButtonSubmit.setEnabled(false);//désactive le bouton par défaut
    mFamilyName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            mButtonSubmit.setEnabled(!editable.toString().isEmpty());
        }

    });
    mButtonSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
```

does anyone has a solution to help me ?

Comment: you have posted only small piece of code, a bit cutted... also post related exception from `Logcat`

Comment: 2021-08-25 10:53:12.174 207-209/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup34: Permission denied
2021-08-25 10:53:12.176 207-209/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup35: Permission denied
2021-08-25 10:53:12.173 207-207/? W/Binder:207_1: type=1400 audit(0.0:683): avc: denied { read } for name="wakeup34" dev="sysfs" ino=19156 scontext=u:r:system_suspend:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 here is part of the logcat

Comment: do you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` line in manifest?

Comment: i don't see it in my AndroidManifest.

Comment: consider adding, lack of this permission is often cause of your exception

Comment: doesn't work, still have the same issue

Comment: try to get permission from user at runtime.

Comment: how can i get it?